# Web Service method signature changed to request/response objects for datatype string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have two websites, both using .Net framework 3.5. One website is hosting a soap web service and the other is referencing this service.
I'm having some unexpected happenings with my web method signatures. I have a simple method in my web service with a signature such as:

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] HelloWorld()
{
    return new[] { "Hello World" };
}
```

But when I reference this web service using the 'Add Service Reference' feature in VS2008, with configuration set to "Always generate message contracts" (although when i check the 'reuse types in referenced assemblies', i seem to have the same issue), the signature seems to be changed by the auto generated proxy objects to the following:

```
HelloWorldResponse HelloWorld(HelloWorldRequest request)
```

I've tried to look this up on the net, but having trouble finding something that will simply explain to me why this is happening, and whether I can/should try to work around it?

I also have this question:
How does one determine whether they should choose the service reference configuration option to "reuse types in referenced assemblies" and "always generated message contracts"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [message-contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) option might have this effect; the purpose here being to allow fine-grained control over the underlying request. Ultimately, what you *are* sending (behind the scenes) *is* a request payload.

The reuse-types option is more typically used with objects (not things like `string[]`) - and means that if you have a 100% matching `Customer` (say) class locally, it can re-use that for the web-service rather than generating a proxy type.

Additionally, note that you aren't actually consuming a WCF service (`[WebMethod]` is the older web-service style). As such you may have better results with a "Web Reference"; when adding the service, hit "Advanced", then "Add Web Reference...". This uses the older UI and wsdl.exe to generate code *intended* for `[WebMethod]` (asmx), rather than WCF (svc).

Of course, rather than *hosting* a `[WebMethod]`, you could (since the server is also 3.5) host a WCF service; this may make things easier.

A final point of WCF; if you *really want* the same contract at client and server, you can use either assembly or class sharing to use the very same types at both end. This is not supported for `[WebMethod]`, though.

Comment: ++1 for suggesting using WCF for the service. OP: Microsoft considers ASMX to be "legacy technology". Since you're already using it for the client, you should start using it for your services.